# Cross-compiling Alpine Linux packages

Tags: cross-compiling, alpine-linux

I'm trying to rebuild Alpine packages on an `x86_64` host for an `armhf` target.  As far as I can tell, the correct way to do this is to clone https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports and run `scripts/bootstrap.sh armhf` to create a chroot environment that can then be used to cross-compile packages.  So far I've:

- Added `${HOME}/packages/main` to `/etc/apk/repositories`
- Created a key with `abuild-keygen -a`
- Made that key trusted with `cp ${HOME}/.abuild/*.pub /etc/apk/keys`

But the bootstrap script still fails with:

```
c4a5a8fbf023:~/aports$ scripts/bootstrap.sh armhf
>>> bootstrap-armhf: Building cross-compiler
>>> binutils-armhf: Package is up to date
>>> gcc-armhf: abuild 3.2.0-r0
>>> gcc-armhf: Checking sanity of /home/builder/aports/main/gcc/APKBUILD...
>>> WARNING: gcc-armhf: g++ should not be in makedepends
>>> gcc-armhf: Analyzing dependencies...
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  .makedepends-gcc-armhf-0:
    masked in: cache
    satisfies: world[.makedepends-gcc-armhf]
  musl (missing):
    required by:
  musl-dev (missing):
    required by:
>>> ERROR: gcc-armhf: all failed
>>> gcc-armhf: Uninstalling dependencies...
```

`musl` and `musl-dev` are packages built for armhf and are in `${HOME}/packages/main/armhf`.

Can someone point me to the right magic to get this to work?  Is there some documentation on this somewhere that I've missed?

Comment: I'm looking to try this, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Rich No.  I've ended up using two docker containers; one based on alpine 3.9 amd64 where I build & host a cross-compiler to build the binaries, the other based on alpine 3.9 armhf where I build the packages.  It is possible to do it in a single container using qemu and a native armhf gcc, but it is horrendously slow, at least for my case.  I'm building golang executables, and cross-compiling takes a couple of minutes compared to over ten hours under qemu.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I've really taken to Alpine for it's many useful features, but documentation isn't one of them.

Comment: FYI, we've also found that using Docker and QEMU makes this much easier than just QEMU natively.  "FROM multiarch/alpine:arm64-v3.9" At least for a single target it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well I had same error but I solved it by doing these steps :
1. `abuild-keygen -a` and then i saved my key with name **mykey**  and got my keys  ( both private and public ) in my current directory.
2. Then just move **mykey.pub** into /etc/apk/keys
3. Then build your cross compile toolchain by `CBUILDROOT=/path/to/buildroot ./scripts/bootstrap.sh armhf` and one more thing , don't create your CBUILDROOT directly or manually,  just let bootstrap script create it.
Let me know if you failed again.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem, it was because in my eagerness I ran the bootstrap script before setting up my package signing key. This meant that the bootstrap sysroot was not populated with the package signing key [because the bootstrapper only copies it over on its initial run](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh#L62), and this led to the error messages shown above. Manually copying the key into `~/sysroot-armhf/etc/apk/keys` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
abuild-keygen -a -i and install sudo
```

Comment: code only answer are ok, but if you add some comments to them you will make your answer easier to understand and easier to find!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working `abuild` environment, the correct answer is the final step in @Golu's answer:

```
CBUILDROOT=~/sysroot-armhf ~/aports/scripts/bootstrap.sh armhf
```

I still can't figure out from reading the source code why this works. `CBUILDROOT` is actually set by the script. It does include a trailing `/`, which I guess potentially might cause issues. Once the process gets going, setting `CBUILDROOT` manually stops being necessary. Anyway, this worked for me, which is why I'm leaving a new answer.